# Android typeface changed after i pack my project

Tags: android, typeface, packed

My app display normal on any other phone except my XIAOMI 2A,the typeface changed.
What is confusing that when I run the app directly, the typeface is ok, but after I packed the protected, the typeface changes. How colud this be?
[image: this is the screenshoot after i packed the project。]
[image: this is the screenshoot when i run the prodect directly。]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your proguard settings. It might be a reference that gets fouled up by the obfuscation process.